# Add percentage column and Frequency of values that are not in top10 most frequent values

Tags: r

below are the codes to get the top 10 most frequent values in one of the variables in my data frame.

```
#Remove NAs
dataL[dataL == "NA"] <- NA
dataS <- na.omit(dataL)

#getting the Top10 frequent values
Y <- dataS$Variable
X <- sort(table(Y), decreasing=TRUE)[1:10]
Z <- data.frame(X)
colnames(Z)= c("Value", "Frequency")
```

And this is the output of it

```
    Value      Frequency
1   1           635
2   0           296
3   1,000,000   115
4   10,000,000  110
5   20,000,000  104
6   5,000,000   101
7   50,000,000  86
8   25,000,000  85
9   30,000,000  80
10  40,000,000  77
```

And I want to output a Frequency % of total on a new column. And also add a Missing values frequency and the frequency of all other values that are not in top10. So the output should look like below.

```
    Value       Frequency    % of Total
0   Missing     67          0.50%
1   1           635         4.60%
2   0           296         2.10%
3   1,000,000   115         0.80%
4   10,000,000  110         0.80%
5   20,000,000  104         0.70%
6   5,000,000   101         0.70%
7   50,000,000  86          0.60%
8   25,000,000  85          0.60%
9   30,000,000  80          0.60%
10  40,000,000  77          0.60%
11  All other   12,136      87.40%
```

Comment: I know how to get the number of missings which is sum(is.na(dataV)). But I don't know how to subtract the Missing Frequency and the Frequencies of all the top 10 from the total values, to get the "All other"

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you want.
First, make up some data. Note argument `useNA = "ifany"` in the call to `table` and that I do **not** subset `X`, I use the entire table.

```
set.seed(5787)    # Make the results reproducible
p <- runif(100)
Y <- sample(100, 1e4, TRUE, prob = p/sum(p))
Y[sample(100, 10)] <- NA
X <- sort(table(Y, useNA = "ifany"), decreasing=TRUE)
Z <- data.frame(X)
colnames(Z)= c("Value", "Frequency")
Z$Value <- as.character(Z$Value)
```

Now, just compute the parts and put the pieces together.

```
Z[['% of Total']] <- 100*Z[["Frequency"]]/sum(Z[["Frequency"]])
Other <-  c("All Other", colSums(Z[-c(1:10, which(is.na(Z$Value))), 2:3]))
Z <- rbind(Z[is.na(Z$Value), ], head(Z, n = 10), Other)

Z$Value[is.na(Z$Value)] <- "Missing"
row.names(Z) <- NULL
Z
#       Value Frequency % of Total
#1    Missing        10        0.1
#2         61       202       2.02
#3         13       200          2
#4         23       197       1.97
#5         55       197       1.97
#6         16       196       1.96
#7         25       189       1.89
#8         48       189       1.89
#9         58       185       1.85
#10        79       183       1.83
#11        54       181       1.81
#12 All Other      8081      80.81
```

Comment: @Bustergun Thanks for accepting the answer. In the mean time I have noticed a small bug, that when computing the totals for `Others` I had also included the row with the `NA` value. It's now corrected. (Just changed the line where `colSums` is used.)

Comment: What will I change to the colSums?

Comment: Just a follow up question how do you make the values on the "% of Total" have a percent sign in it? (e.g. 2.02%)? And also fix the decimal points into just 2 decimal places because when I try to run it on my data it has a lot of decimals.

Comment: @Bustergun Use `Z[['% of Total']] <- paste0(Z[['% of Total']], "%")`.